# Как открыть RSA ключ из файла

Tags: java, rsa

```
File f = new File(filename);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
dis.readFully(keyBytes);
dis.close();        
RSAPrivateKeySpec spec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger(keyBytes),new BigInteger(keyBytes));
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
kf.generatePrivate(spec);
```

Фаил открывается, но возник вопрос как узнать modulus и private exponent имея последовательность байтов keyBytes. RSAPrivateKeySpec входными параметрами должна получать modulus и private exponent, у меня данных значений нет и я везде вставил new BigInteger(keyByte), но это не правильно и соответственно расшифровать ничего не получиться, зашифрованное таким ключом.

Comment: Формат этого файла не документирован?

Comment: я для себя не нашел ответа, может вы подскажете?

Comment: Ну для начала неплохо было бы узнать, откуда он вообще получен.

Comment: ключ генерировал gpg --gen-key - ответил на все вопросы мастера и получил запись в хранилище. после этого я сделал экспорт ключа gpg --export-secret-key -a -o mysecret.key

Comment: Я думаю, в GPG должна быть функция импорта ключа, по аналогии с CryptoAPI, в котором я более-менее разбираюсь. Стоит порыться на предмет этого

Comment: можете показать к сделать такое на CryptoAPI. ПО задаче мне нужно подгрузить private.key и получить подпись к строке. Основная проблема это подгрузка RSA ключа.

Comment: Ну что сказать. а) CryptoAPI это Win-специфический интерфейс. бэ) у меня таких задач  никогда не возникало вэ) CryptoAPI - этой слой между прикладной программой и криптопровайдером, т.е. конкретная реализация запрятана в провайдер, в контексте которого и выполняются операции. гэ) Можно посмотреть в окрестностях функции CryptImportKey, хотя пользы будет немного

Comment: Понятно, мне это не подойдет. Пошел дальше курить маны, может пойму наконец как это все работает. Спасибо за помощь.